# Google Test - How to test a marix of classes and tests (C++11)

Tags: googletest

I have to do the same 5 tests on 3 classes.

Is there some way to avoid writing 15 separate tests, besides macros?
(Essentially creating 15 tests by looping over 3 classes / 5 string values)

Ca C++14.

Comment: Probably too obvious a question: Are the classes somehow related, and do the tests deal with related methods?

Comment: same static method (overridden versions) in different classes (not instantiated)

Comment: A bit similar to this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256758/can-googletest-value-parameterized-with-multiple-different-types-of-parameters?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa